# Can I install Polymer (1.0) with NPM?

Tags: npm, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to use Polymer on a new project, and was trying to avoid using Bower in favor of NPM for front-end dependency management.

The [getting started](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/getting-the-code.html) page gives instructions for using Bower (and using a .zip file, etc...) but no mention of NPM.

I have used NPM by pointing directly at a GitHub repo before, but I cannot seem to get this to work for Polymer.

*When I run this:*

```
npm install git@github.com:Polymer/polymer.git#v1.0.5
```

*I get this error:*

> npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: git@'github.com:Polymer/polymer.git'
>
> npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
>
> npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4","0.1.5"]

Is there something I'm missing, or do I need to bite the bullet and use Bower?

Comment: Full support for Polymer in NPM is coming soon: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326. It's being actively worked on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the earlier answers, Polymer has now indeed [become available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/polymer) on NPM. To install it:

```
npm i Polymer
```

Note that it doesn't include the standard elements collection; those can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-polymer-elements):

```
npm i npm-polymer-elements
```

You can then include them in your HTML:

```
<!-- for custom elements -->
<link rel="import" href="/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer.html"/>
<!-- for standard elements -->
<link rel="import" href="/node_modules/paper-button/paper-button.html"/>
<paper-button>click</paper-button>
```

Unfortunately loading Polymer through webpack currently [doesn't seem possible yet](https://github.com/JonDum/polymer-loader/issues/1), meaning if your `node_modules` (or `bower_components`) folder isn't in a publicly accessible location, you may want to make a Grunt/Gulp task to copy it over for after future updates...

Comment: Instead of using the `npm-polymer-elements` package, you can also get individual packages for each element maintained by the official project's user account: https://www.npmjs.com/~polymer

For example, you can get `@polymer/paper-button` or `@polymer/iron-flex-layout`

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, but I ran into trouble with 'npm i @polymer/polymer'... 'npm i Polymer' (note the capital 'P') appears to work fine though.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 2016/10/25**
The Polymer team announced at the [Polymer Summit 2016](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guYHn0P8bKQ&t=17m48s) that they will be looking into supporting `npm` via [yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn).

`[sudo] npm install -g yarn
yarn add Polymer
yarn install --flat`

**OLD AWNSER**

There is currently **no way** I know of to get polymer running with NPM.

Polymer is meant to work with Bower. All dependencies of a Polymer that are declared in https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/bower.json like `webcomponentsjs` will not be downloaded. Therefor if you don't want to download every dependency manually you should use bower.

Comment: Do you have any idea if this is something they plan to make available in the future? Maybe for NPM3?

Comment: No I don't think so. Bower was build to manage dependencies for web applications and there is really no point in using NPM, which was build for managing dependencies for node applications.

Comment: Ehh... more and more people are moving away from Bower for front-end dependency management in favor of NPM. Check out [this NPM blog entry](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging), [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@nickheiner/why-my-team-uses-npm-instead-of-bower-eecfe1b9afcb), and [this Bower GitHub *issue*](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1520). I personally have made the switch months ago, and am very reluctant to go back. When NPM3 comes out, it should really put the nail in the coffin.

Comment: The Polymer team is interested in using npm in the future, and has discussed this with the good folks at npm. There are still a few wrinkles to work out, but npm3 brings us **much** closer to being able to use npm directly. You can find more discussion here:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326#issuecomment-113594766

Comment: sheesh , I havn't used bower in 6 months

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/~polymer is official account. Polymer (capital P) is not official polymer package: "The reason I've published https://www.npmjs.com/package/Polymer
because I cannot fetch packages behind my company firewall which are
pointing to github.com,
we have policy to reject all queries to github.com, but we need a polymer"  https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326#issuecomment-241373023

Answer (score 5):

The main problem with Polymer is that the tagged build commits don't have a `package.json`, making it impossible to install them with `npm` (e.g. see [v1.1.1](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/tree/v1.1.1)). This means that in order to install Polymer with `npm` you'll need some helper tool. Perhaps the best candidate for this is [Napa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/napa).

Napa is a package for installing git projects that do not have a (valid) `package.json`. The npm page already explains how to use it, here a quick summary for Polymer:

1. `npm install napa --save-dev`
2. Update your `package.json` to include this (replace x.y.z with the version you want):

   ```
   {
       "scripts" : {
           "install" : "napa"
       },
       "napa" : {
           "polymer" : "polymer/polymer#vX.Y.Z"
       }
   }
   ```

Note that `napa` just clones the repo into the `node_modules` folder, hence no dependencies of polymer will be installed alongside of it, but you can keep all of the configuration in your `package.json` instead of having to use bower.

Comment: Hadn't heard of napa, thats pretty cool. Still might not really be a solution for this however: it seems that Polymer doesn't but their distributable files in the git repo directly, and rather makes them accessible as .zip files on their [releases](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/releases) page. With this solution I guess you would have to actually *build* polymer as part of your build step.

Comment: Polymer maintains a separate build branch where the built versions are (which are tagged as well). See for example the commit tagged [v.1.1.1](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/tree/v1.1.1) on their repo, it only contains the built and nothing of the source.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice that at first.

Answer (score -13):

Try installing *bower* method!

```
"npm install -g bower"
```

Then type *inside your folder*:

```
"bower init"
```

Follow the instructions, then type:

```
"bower install --save Polymer/polymer
```

Create an *index.html* file and start to work!!!

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote, and I appreciate the effort, but this does not answer the question. The bower install is clearly documented.